# Adding missing records to total count (integer) while grouping by in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have an odd situation where I have two collections. One Collection basically contains all ItemID's from my items, where the other one contains only ItemID's who had sales (including the sales data).

Now I've determined that ItemID's from Collections #1 that are not present in Collection #2 has 0 sales. Now the situation where I'm not sure what to do is following:

```
var items = new List<Collection1>(); // Contains all ItemIDs where ItemID is a plain string

var itemsTransactions = new List<Collection2>(); // contains item id's that have sales.
```

now in third step I'm grouping by itemsTransationCollection by property called Username like this:

```
var groupedByUsername = itemTransactions
    .GroupBy( x => x.Username )
    .Select( item => new MyClass
    {
        TotalItems = item
            .Select( x => x.ItemID )
            .Count(), // sub query should be performed here... ?

        SuccessfulItems = item
            .Select( x => x.ItemID )
            .Count()
    } )
    .ToList();
```

Now the trick is here is that calculation for successful items is already correct because the itemsTransactions collection already contains ONLY item id's that actually have sales...

I'm not sure how to make that comparison that I just mentioned above to include the missing items into the count for this property `TotalItems`?

So my question here is, is it possible to do a subquery while grouping by in LINQ to add the missing items into the count of property `TotalItems`?

Can someone help me out?

@DavidLee so the output should look something like this:

```
Username  TotalItems(sold + unsold)  Successful items( only ones with sales)
DavidLee    5                                                   2

xyz         4                                                   1
Ronaldo     19                                                  12
```

Successful items shouldn't be larger than TotalListings (it couldn't be mathematically possible)

For @Vlad sample input and desired output:

Items collection

ItemID     Username

1          Seller1
2          Seller2
3          Seller3
4          Seller4
5          Seller5

itemsTransactions collection:

```
ItemID     Username     Sales

1          Seller1       2
2          Seller2       4 
3          Seller3       5 
4          Seller4       6 
5          Seller5       7 
5          Seller5       4
```

The itemsTransactions collection contains ungrouped data for sales... That's why I'm grouping it in 3rd step...

Comment: Maybe to add 2nd group by parameter and then do something with it ?

Comment: Does your first list 'items' contain anything to identify the user by? Or are there only ids?

Comment: @VladStryapko yes it contains everything that 2nd collection does... They are essentially same type (items colleciton contains ItemID and Username as well)

Comment: Will `TotalItems` be the same number across all records?

Comment: @DavidLee it shouldn't be ... each username has unique number of TotalItems determined by query =)

Comment: @User987 So basically you want to see the total items sold to a user in the `SuccessfulItems` and all the items the user did not purchase in the `TotalItems`?

Comment: @DavidLee yes yes that's it, TotalItems is sold + unsold =)

Comment: @User987 That contradicts what i just said before so now i am confused again.  Wouldn't `Sold` + `Unsold` be the same for every user?

Comment: @DavidLee yes the formula is the same, but the number received by the formula wouldn't be the same , if that's what you mean ? :D

Comment: @User987 It would be much easier to help you if you have posted your `Collection1` and `Collection2` classes, some code that populates the `items` and `ItemTransactions` with sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @IvanStoev one second i will post entire class .. But basically they are same type ...

Comment: @User987 I guess I am having trouble understanding your data.  `Sold` + `Unsold` to me means every item in the items collection.  So the `Sold` and `Unsold` might be different for each user, but the sum of the two should always be the same for every user?

Comment: @DavidLee I have provided sample output in my original question

Comment: @User987 Okay so I get the sold number, can you please explain more what an unsold item is?

Comment: @DavidLee Unsold item is the item from items collection that is not present in itemsTransaction collection (because itemsTransactions collections only contains items that actually have sales). So the criteria by which items would be unsold is that the itemID from items collection (#1) isn't present in #2 collection

Comment: @User987
From what I see in your example data, each user has more total items than sold. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @VladStryapko We're not looking into individual sales of the each item, but rather how many of them has sales and how many of those items has no sales... ItemID can have 60 sales but he should be treated as 1 successful item in successfulitem property

Comment: @User987 I see what going on here. okay so the items collection is by user, that was main point of confusion.  i should be able to put together a query for you.

Comment: @DavidLee Yes that's it =)

Comment: @User987 Posted an answer, let me know if it doesn't work for you and we can figure something else out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final version of solution:

```
   var result = itemsTransactions.GroupBy(_ => _.Name).Select(_ =>
    new
    {
        SuccessfulCount = _.Select(_ => _.ItemId).Distinct().Count(),
        TotalCount = items.Where(item => item.Name == _.Key).Select(it => it.ItemId).Distinct().Count()
    });
```

Comment: Hey Vlad thanks a lot for the reply, with the first query in some cases I get higher values for successful items rather than for Total items (Total items = 1 , successful = 4 ?) lol

Comment: Are you sure your initial data is correct? Could you provide an example of input which causes such output?

Comment: sure one sec I will post in my original question :)

Comment: I've checked the data and xyz has 4 total items and only 1 sold. It seems OK to me. What's the issue?

Comment: Hey Vlad, I'm honestly myself abit confused now... :D So let's say we have like this: ItemID=5 has 60 sales, ItemID=6 has 40 sales, and ItemID=2 has 0 sales... The output should be: TotalListings - 3, Succsessful listings: 2

Comment: Hey Vlad, in this section: Count(_ => _.Username == group.Key) I'm not able to select the Username as property, all it enlists me are usual linq methods like select, count and stuff like that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148535/discussion-between-vlad-stryapko-and-user987).

Answer (score 1):

I would make two subqueries and then join them.  I think the main issue is using the itemsTransaction collection as the starting query, although can be done, IMO it is easier to start with the items collection.  Very verbose and can be shortened but I find it much easier to understand what is going on.

```
var itemsByUser = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Username)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Username = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    };

var itemsWithSalesByUser = itemTransactions
    .GroupBy(x => x.Username)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Username = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    };

var joinedDataQuery =
    from i in itemsByUser 
    join s in itemsWithSalesByUser 
        on i.Username equals s.Username into sj
    from s in sj.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
    select new MyClass
    {
         Username = i.Username
         TotalItems = i.Count,
         SuccessfulItems = s == null ? 0 : s.Count
    };

// this when it goes to memory so building up the queries 
// in separate variables will not have any performance impacts.
var joinedData = joinedDataQuery.ToList();
```

EDIT: changed `=` to `equals`

EDIT: account for possible missing successful items.

Comment: i grouped itemsByUser, might not be necessary if there is a distinct number of records there, wasn't sure so i did it anyways and doesn't really effect anything.